# How to download as pdf from chrome printing preview in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, download

I have a button to click, it will open a printing dialog, I need to select the destination Save as PDF then press print and save the file.

I tried

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
HashMap<String, Object> chromeOptionsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromeOptionsMap.put("plugins.plugins_disabled", new String[] { "Chrome PDF Viewer "});      
chromeOptionsMap.put("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);
chromeOptionsMap.put("download.default_directory", "C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads");
chromeOptionsMap.put("download,promt_for_download",false);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromeOptionsMap);
options.addArguments("--headless"); */
```

but still can't select Save as PDF
The above code seems to print HTML code as a pdf

Comment: I also use chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", new java.util.HashMap<String, Object>() {{
       put("plugins.plugins_disabled", new String[]{"Chrome PDF Viewer"});
       put("download.default_directory", "C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\PDF"); // Set the download directory
       put("printing.print_preview_sticky_settings", new java.util.HashMap<String, Object>() {{
           put("savefile.default_directory", "C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\PDF"); // Set the default save directory
       }});
   }});  But printing dialog didn't take these  preferences